# I have a five 12 V DC motors and I want to use an SMPS instead of lithium battery

Tags: batteries, motor, switch-mode-power-supply, lithium-ion, lithium

I have five 12 V, 3 A DC motors and a lithium battery pack, 12 V, 30 Ah and an SMPS, 12 V 30 A. Can I use the SMPS as the motor power supply instead of batteries?

Comment: Make the motors start separately, not in same moment

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course.

It's not that easy though finding an SMPS that is able to deliver to the motors a steady current of 15 A steadily and and istantaneous current of 150 A.

The SMPS output voltage must remain stable under any working condition.

That means that you should provide a fairly big capacitance at the input and output of the SMPS in order to fulfill the current peak requests of the motor.

You might also want to pick an SMPS which works at a frequency higher than 250 KHz.

You might want to pick a multi-phase buck converter like:

https://www.ti.com/product/TPS53679

https://www.ti.com/lit/an/slva882a/slva882a.pdf?ts=1616002070641&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F